# Edits to help center: call for proposals

Tags: discussion

This site has a [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help) that should be the first port of call when educating new users about this site (or when they seek to educate themselves).

As things stand, we have not fully exploited the potential to customize this resource to our needs. This question is therefore a call for proposals for what should be included in the help center.

[Here is an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259920/274708) from the network Meta that details which parts of the help center we are able to edit.

Answer (score 4):

I think we should address homework questions directly in the introduction. This is by far the most common issue here. My subjective belief is that 90% of all question closed are homework questions.

I wish there was a way to hint users to our homework policy the moment they are typing in their question.